# PHP Basic Regex preg replace not working on end of string chars

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, email-validation

I have an email function that send out email by the user input. Some of my users copy / paste email address from their clients and it comes surrounded with the greater then/ lesser then symbols ( > < ).

Example: < user@domain.com >

I'm trying to get read of these symbols so I would get a correct email address. I tried preg replace but it doesnt work on the &gt symbol at the end of the string. What am I doind wrong?

The Function:

```
function strip_arrows($text) {
                $text = preg_replace('#^<#', '', $text);
                $text = preg_replace('#^>#', '', $text);
                $text = preg_replace('#^&lt#', '', $text);
                $text = preg_replace('#^&gt#', '', $text);
                return $text;
            }
```

Cheers!

Comment: You use a "start of the string" anchor `^`. remove it.

Answer (score 4):

<s>You are not using a standard Regular expression syntax. In fact, I don't think this would be valid anywhere.</s> And really you don't need it for this example. Simply trim the characters, after you decode them.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

```
$text = trim(html_entity_decode($text), "< >");
```

Comment: "You are not using a standard Regular expression syntax" Why?

Comment: I got confused about the ^ symbol. And because I've done a lot of JS programming, I didn't even know that PHP could use other delimiters than the standard `/`. I've never seen other delimiters in any standard PCRE specification.

Comment: With PHP you can use as delimiter almost all ascii characters that are not letters or digits, even sillier (like `|` `?` `+` `*`). You can use brackets too : `[regex]`, `(regex)`, `{regex}`

Comment: The use of delimiters comes from the PHP syntax, but is not a PCRE specification: http://pcre.org/pcre.txt . Note that in Javascript you have two possible syntaxes, one with delimiters and an other without.

Comment: Yes. At the moment I saw your comment on the question, and re-read his question, I realized that something was fishy. It's why it took me so long to answer your comment. I went on to find what are the acceptable delimiters in PHP regex flavor.
In JavaScript I use regex literals simply because my IDE highlights them differently than just strings.

Answer (score 0):

@Casimir et Hippolyte thank you for your answer! I removed the `^` sign, I didn't know it's a "start of string" anchor.

Final Fixed Code:

```
function strip_arrows($text) {
                $text = preg_replace('#<#', '', $text);
                $text = preg_replace('#>#', '', $text);
                $text = preg_replace('#&lt#', '', $text);
                $text = preg_replace('#&gt#', '', $text);
                return $text;
}
```

Comment: Happy for you, however AlexanderMP approach is from far better here.

Comment: His approach didn't work for me, I was still left with the closing > sign.

Comment: @SirCode-A-lot, interesting. This shouldn't ever happen. Trim(), indeed, is the function designed to do exactly what you wanted to do. Either your input is not as described, or there was an error in copying the line of code. I strongly advise you to try and make trim() work, so you could learn its functionality and use it in the future each time you need some characters removed from start or end of string.
Although regex works, it is both an overkill, and makes the intention harder to read in the code, while making the code larger, and more prone to bugs.

Answer (score 0):

A fast way to do that is to use [`strtr()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) (since you are replacing literal strings, you don't need to use regexes):

```
function strip_arrows($text) {
    $trans = array('<' => '', '>' => '', '&lt;' => '', '&gt;' => '');
    return strtr($text, $trans);
}
```